# Why can't I echo all variables correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, echo

**Edited, please scroll down**
I am trying to display 3 variables which consist of data stored in a SQL database. However, only the first gets echoed successfully (`topLeftUrl`). It is worth noting that the same PHP file also receives data from an input (also in the same PHP file) and stores it in the same SQL database. This code was written for testing purposes and may not be entirely safe.

```
//Connect
$con = mysqli_connect ("localhost","noneedtoknow","noneedtoknow","noneedtoknow");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Error: ", mysql_connect_error(), "<br>";
    die ();
}

//Store input in SQL database
$result = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT * FROM edit");
$message = stripslashes ($_POST ['message']);
if ($message !== '') {
    mysqli_query ($con, "UPDATE edit SET cont='$message' WHERE id='message'"); }
$topLeftNew = ($_POST ['topLeftUrl']);
if ($topLeftNew !== '') {
    mysqli_query ($con, "UPDATE edit SET cont='$topLeftNew' WHERE id='topLeft'"); }
$topRightNew = ($_POST ['topRightUrl']);
if ($topRightNew !== '') {
    mysqli_query ($con, "UPDATE edit SET cont='$topRightNew' WHERE id='topRight'"); }

//First echo
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result))
{
    if ($row["id"] == "topLeft" && $done2 == 0)
    {
        $topLeftUrl = $row["cont"];
    }
}
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"topLeftUrl\" value=\"" . $topLeftUrl . "\">";

//Second echo
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result))
{
    if ($row["id"] == "topRight" && $done3 == 0)
    {
        $topRightUrl = $row["cont"];
    }
}
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"topRightUrl\" value=\"" . $topRightUrl . "\">";

//Third echo
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result))
{
    if ($row["id"] == "message" && $done == 0)
    {
        echo $row["cont"];
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
I updated the code, and the problem seems to have changed. For some reason, `echo $messageCont;` displays an old value of `cont WHERE id='message'`. The database itself is updated successfully, though, and I see the new value of `cont` once I refresh the page/re-submit the form. Why do I not see the current value of `cont` immediately after form submission, though? Here is the new code:

```
/* Before <!DOCTYPE html> */
//Connect
$con = mysqli_connect ("localhost","noneedtoknow","noneedtoknow","noneedtoknow");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Error: ", mysql_connect_error(), "<br>";
    die ();
}

//Query and update
$result = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT * FROM edit");
$message = stripslashes ($_POST ['message']);
if ($message !== '') {
    mysqli_query ($con, "UPDATE edit SET cont='$message' WHERE id='message'"); }
$topLeftNew = ($_POST ['topLeftUrl']);
if ($topLeftNew !== '') {
    mysqli_query ($con, "UPDATE edit SET cont='$topLeftNew' WHERE id='topLeft'"); }
$topRightNew = ($_POST ['topRightUrl']);
if ($topRightNew !== '') {
    mysqli_query ($con, "UPDATE edit SET cont='$topRightNew' WHERE id='topRight'"); }

//Query again and read
$done0 = 0;
$done1 = 0;
$done2 = 0;
mysqli_data_seek ($result, 0);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result))
{
    if ($row["id"] == "topLeft" && $done0 == 0)
    {
        $topLeftUrl = $row["cont"];
        $done0 = 1;
    }
    else if ($row["id"] == "topRight" && $done1 == 0)
    {
        $topRightUrl = $row["cont"];
        $done1 = 1;
    }
    else if ($row["id"] == "message" && $done2 == 0)
    {
        $messageCont = $row["cont"];
        $done2 = 1;
    }
    else null;
}

/* After <!DOCTYPE html> */
/* Form code was omitted as it works perfectly. It is in this same file, though. */
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"topLeftUrl\" value=\"" . $topLeftUrl . "\">";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"topRightUrl\" value=\"" . $topRightUrl . "\">";
echo $messageCont;
```

Any help is appreciated.
**Edit:** I only had to replace `mysqli_data_seek ()` with the line beginning by `$result` (cut/paste). Thank you.

Comment: The syntax is [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) and not `strip_slashes` unless you have a seperate/custom function.

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs using `mysql_connect_error()` - they do not mix. Use `or die(mysqli_error($con))`

Comment: Yes, edited the stripslashes(). Anyhow, that was not the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to loop over the result set three times? Because the way you're doing it, the second loop will take off from where the first one stopped.

Comment: man, just use prepared statements instead, you're already using mysqli  anyway

Comment: @scrowler: Ah, I see. Should I use a different `$result` variable to prevent that from happening?

Comment: You could try calling `mysqli_data_seek($result, 0)` before each loop to reset the internal pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this same problem on my site....you run multiple mysql_fetch_array() on the same query ($result)...I thought this would work on my site but this failed for all but the first of 6 while loops which all referenced the same query on my site (I'm sorry but I don't remember the exact error message in my error_log). Try condensing your 3 while loops into 1 loop, something like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {
    if ($row["id"] == "topLeft" && $done2 == 0) {
        $topLeftUrl = $row["cont"];
    } else if ($row["id"] == "topRight" && $done3 == 0) {
        $topRightUrl = $row["cont"];
    } else if ($row["id"] == "message" && $done == 0) {
        echo $row["cont"];
    } else null;
}
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"topRightUrl\" value=\"" . $topRightUrl . "\">";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"topLeftUrl\" value=\"" . $topLeftUrl . "\">";
```

Comment: I've followed your advice, but I have another problem now, which is described in my question (I edited it).